# Get current entity id and use in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm creating a report which is scoped to individual record level for Service Cases in Dynamics CRM 2011.

This report has 4 datasets; 1. Filter, 2. TicketDetails, 3. Materials and, 4. Labour.

The Filter dataset is there to grab the IncidentId of the current service case being viewed in CRM.

```
SELECT IncidentId FROM FilteredIncident AS CRMAF_FilteredIncident
```

I have a parameter called incidentfilter, it's source is the Filter dataset. CRM seems to be ignoring the CRMAF_ prefix and just returning all service cases.

Datasets 2 and 4 are both have a where clause to filter on the incidentfilter parameter value. Dataset 3, queries GP, for that I pass in the TicketNumber field from the service case.

My report seems to be running, it's just that it retrieves every service case from CRM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had similar problem with CRM ignoring the CRMAF_Prefix. You can try this:

1. Just to make sure, do you have more than one table you are trying to apply the   CRMAF_prefix on? If you have, make sure you limit the number of tables to just one.
2. You could try to add the CRMAF_prefix to the fields as well:

SELECT CRMAF_FilteredIncident.IncidentId FROM FilteredIncident AS CRMAF_FilteredIncident